# display product information php

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

Hi I am a beginner at php and learning to develop a eCommerce page.
The problem i am facing is that i can have a product grid with my products. now I want to click on the product image or a button called "info" which the displays the information instead of creating a page for every single item. it does go to the page but it displays only the header and footer and not the 
The link in the bar does get the id for the product.

I am using MVC so here is the code:

```
Model: ProductDataSet.php

public function fetchProductInformation($productID) {
  $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE (productID = :productID)';
  $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare a PDO statement
  $statement->execute(); // execute the PDO statement
    $dataSet = [];
    while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
       $dataSet[] = new ProductData($row);
    }

    return $dataSet;
}

View: product
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['emailaddress'])){

}
?>
<?php require('template/header.phtml') ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <br>

    <?php foreach ($view->productDataSet  as $productData) {
        if (count($view->productDataSet)>0) {
         echo '<div class = "col-xs-6 .col-sm-3">';
        echo '<a href="product.php?id=' . $productData->getProductID(). '"><img src="images/'. $productData->getPhoto(). ' "alt="no picture" height = ""  width = ""/> </a>' ."\n";
        echo "<p>" . $productData->getTitle(). "</p>\n";
          echo "<p>" . $productData->getDescription(). "</p>\n";
        echo "<p>£" . $productData->getPrice(). ".000</p>\n";
        //  echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href =productDetails.php?product='.$product->getProduct().'>view</a>';
        echo '<a href="productDetails.php?ProductID='. $productData->getProductID().'><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button></a>';
        echo '<a href="product.php"><input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary " value="Add to basket"></a>';
      //  echo '<a href="/productDetails.php?id='.$productData->getProductID().'">View details</a>';
        //  echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href =productDetails.php?product='.$product->getProductID().'>view</a>';
        echo "</div>";

    }
  }
    ?>

</form>

<?php require('template/footer.phtml') ?>

VIEW: ProductDetails
<?php require('template/header.phtml') ?>

<h3>Welcome to Page1</h3>
<?php
  echo "<p>" . $productData->getTitle(). "</p>\n";
  ?>
<?php require('template/footer.phtml') ?>

Controller : product

<?php

require_once('Models/ProductDataSet.php');

$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'Products';
$view->productDataSet = null;

    $productDataSet = new productDataSet();
    $view->productDataSet = $productDataSet->fetchAllProducts();

  //  $view->watchDataSet = $watchDataSet->fetchWatch($_GET['id'])[0];

require_once('Views/product.phtml');

Controller Product Details 
<?php

$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'Page1';
require_once('Models/ProductDataSet.php');
$productDataSet = new productDataSet();
if(isset($_GET['productID']))
{
  $productID = $_GET['productID'];
  $view->productDataSet =$productDataSet->fetchProductInformation($productID);
}

require_once('Views/product.phtml');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like you missing the part where you actually bind the parameter to the query you have prepared. `:productID` is only a placeholder in the query when you prepare it, you need to explicitly define `:productID` withing the query.

Observe the below changes to your function:

```
public function fetchProductInformation($productID) {
  $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE (productID = :productID)';
  $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare a PDO statement
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  $statement->bindParam(':productID', $productID);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  $statement->execute(); // execute the PDO statement
  $dataSet = [];
  while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $dataSet[] = new ProductData($row);
  }

  return $dataSet;
}
```

Also, your echo for the `button` element is missing the closing double quote for the `href` property. Below is the fixed version:

```
echo '<a href="productDetails.php?ProductID='. $productData->getProductID().'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button></a>';
```

Comment: still, nothing but I noticed this is the link that is displayed when a product is clicked on
//////////////////////
productDetails.php?ProductID=2><button%20type=
maybe something in the other part is something wrong

Comment: I added on to my answer.

Comment: thanks for that the link is ok but there is not content I have changed to the suggestion that you gave me